# Is there a setting to force HTML edit mode in Eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, settings

I'm doing django dev in Eclipse.  I'd like to edit html template files without having to force them to open in edit mode (because when you just double click on an html file in Eclipse it opens in a browser mode)

Is there a setting to just always open these files in edit mode?

Comment: i think there is a setting in the preferences about "Editors" where you assign the default handler for files.

Comment: I have the answer and screenshots to boot but stackoverflow won't accept my flickr photos shots

Comment: you can upload images in the post you know.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Text Editor doesn't give syntax highlighting or anything, found this page to get a more full featured html editor going.  http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2012/05/eclipse-install-html-editor-plugin.html